# Interaction between fragments slow refresh

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

On my screen I have 2 containers - left for 3 fragments in view pager, right for single fragment. From this on the right I increment some temp variable and through inteface I pass this variable to fragments. I switch fragments in view pager and everything seems to act all right. But, there are two problems.

First is that when I start my app and try to actualize temp variable in third fragment in view pager there is NPE. And of course it should be, because at this point third fragment is not initialized (view pager only initialize actual fragment and the ones on his sides, to be able to slide between fragments). How can I initialize third fragment at the begining? I thought I can store data temporarily in second fragment and when second is initialized I can pass the data to third, but it seems not good solution.

Second question is when I initialize all fragments by sliding on it and I come back to first fragment view of third is gone (but it's initialized). When I actualize temp variable and slide to third fragment I can see this variable but after +- one second. Can someone explain me why? Without this knowledge I can't solve this problem :/

Here you have some code of mine:

```
public class ThirdFragment extends Fragment {

View thisView;
TextView tempTextView;
String iterator;

public AchievFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    iterator = "Start";
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    thisView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_third, container, false);

    tempTextView= (TextView) thisView.findViewById(R.id.tempTextView);
    tempTextView.setText(iterator);

    return  thisView;
}

public void getVariable(String text) {
    iterator = text;
    tempTextView.setText(iterator);
}
```

So it's third fragment class. At the beginning I initialize iterator (it's this temp variable) as a global variable to avoid npe after initializing fragments. And in onCreateView i set the view of TextView to value of this variable. Should work fine, but this +-1 sec offset makes me sad.

I think this sample of code should be enough, the rest is standard I suppose, but if anyone will be really interested I'll past the rest.

I really hope you will understand what I just wrote.

Here is the main (hosting) activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnFragmentInteractionListener {

ViewPager mViewPager;
FragmentPageAdapter ft;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager_container);
    ft = new FragmentPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager.setAdapter(ft);

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    RightFragment gameFragment  = new RightFragment();
    ft.replace(R.id.rightFragment_container, rightFragment,"RightFragment");
    ft.commit();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void OnUpdateFirst(String text) {
    FirstFragment firstFragment = (FirstFragment) ft.instantiateItem(mViewPager,0);
    firstFragment.getVariable(text);
}

@Override
public void OnUpdateSecond(String text) {
    SecondFragment secondFragment = (SecondFragment) ft.instantiateItem(mViewPager,1);
    secondFragment.getVariable(text);
}

@Override
public void OnUpdateThird(String text) {
    ThirdFragment thirdFragment = (ThirdFragment) ft.instantiateItem(mViewPager,2);
    thirdFragment.getVariable(text);
}
```

}

Fragment Page Adapter code:

```
public class FragmentPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public FragmentPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {

    switch (arg0)
    {
        case 0:
            return new FirstFragment();
        case 1:
            return new SecondFragment();
        case 2:
            return new ThirdFragment();
        default:
            break;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
```

Expection when I try to actualize variable on third fragment before I initialize it (in example right after I start app)

```
06-14 16:47:25.621  27246-27246/com.package.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.package.app.ThirdFragment.getVariable(ThirdFragment.java:37)
        at com.package.app.MainActivity.OnUpdateThird(MainActivity.java:59)
        at com.package.app.RightFragment$3.onClick(RightFragment.java:57)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4101)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17082)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4940)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:798)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:565)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please, post code of your hosting activity along with log with your exception

Comment: @OlegOsipenko I posted code of hosting activity and exception log as you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to your first question you can call [`setOffscreenPageLimit(2)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)) method on your ViewPager right after initializing it. By default it is set to 1 that means that adapter creates one page which is on the screen right now and one that is next.

Comment: Okey, this 'trick' solve my two problems. Thank you very much.
Anywya, if someone know and could explain me why this second thing appeared I'll be grateful ;)